# query_posts on category ID doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

```
$posts = query_posts(array('post_type'=>'sedan', 'category'=>'1', 'posts_per_page'=>'4'));
```

The `category` parameter in the above query doesn't seem to work as expected. It is showing all the posts from `Sedan` post type, but I want to specify only categories with `category ID = 1` within `Sedan post type`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with

```
$posts = query_posts(array('post_type'=>'sedan', 'cat'=>'1', 'posts_per_page'=>'4'));
```

`cat` instead of `category`.

Also **don't use** `query_posts()` for your query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Use `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()`

You can achieve the same with:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'sedan', 'category'=>'1', 'posts_per_page'=>'4'));
```

Safer way then modifying the main query.

I always prefer `WP_Query` myself.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'sedan',
    'cat'=>'1',
    'posts_per_page'=>'4'
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

$out = '';

if ($posts->have_posts()){
    while ($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post(); 
        $out .= 'stuff goes here';
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();

return $out;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's a matter of using `cat` and NOT `category`

Comment: Yes, ultimately, but still, use `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()`, just to be safe ;)

Comment: Remember, `category` is as valid parameter in `get_posts`, everything passed to `category` get passed to the `cat` parameter in `WP_Query`  :-)

Comment: Yeah, I edited it to be fully correct. I prefer `WP_Query`, more options :)

Comment: Yes, but it depends. For non paginated queries, `get_posts` are faster as it skips pagination. Alternatively, what I also do is to add `'no_found_rows' => true` to my `WP_Query` arguments for non paginated queries. This is exactly what `get_posts` do by default :-)

Comment: Also note, **all** parameters that can be passed to `WP_Query` can be passed to `get_posts`

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about speed. Then again, in the majority of cases I need pagination (either in regular blog posts, or posts/cpt that are AJAX loaded), that's why I use `WP_Query`. I guess this depends on what the user needs.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `get_posts`  [refrence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

or another option is to use `WP_Query`

```
$new = new WP_Query('post_type=discography&category_name=my-category');
while ($new->have_posts()) : $new->the_post();
     the_content();
    endwhile;
```

or with cat id

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('My Category');
$args=array(
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'post_type' => 'discography',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$new = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

```
$args=array(
'posts_per_page' => 50,    
'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category', //double check your taxonomy name in you db 
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $cat_id,
    ),
   ),
 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```